# Solr cloud production setup on AWS EC2

Tags: solr, solrcloud

how can i set up solr cloud on AWS EC2 instance for holding above 1000 collections?
Can anyone provide me step by step process about this?

Comment: https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_2/aws-solrcloud-tutorial.html

Comment: http://www.francelabs.com/blog/tutorial-deploying-solrcloud-6-on-amazon-ec2/